# Почему не срабатывает powershell из cmd

Tags: windows

Всем привет.
Запускаю в оболочке PowerShell такую строку:

```
$spNote=new-object -com "SAPI.spvoice" ; $spNote.Speak("Ошибка")
```

Все нормально. 
Почему это не срабатывает в командной строке cmd?

```
c:>powershell $spNote=new-object -com "SAPI.spvoice" ; $spNote.Speak("Ошибка")
```

Comment: А командная строка от имени администратора запущена?

Comment: Потому, что [скрипт передаётся не так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help#-command).

Comment: "Потому, что скрипт передаётся не так." А как? Что ошибочно в вышеуказанной строке cmd?

Comment: @Alexey попробуйте экранировать ". Что-то подобное \".

Answer (score 0):

Банальное изменение "Ошибка" на 'Ошибка' все решило.